# Перевод кода С на PHP

Tags: c, php, c++

Здравствуйте, может кто знает программы для перекодировки кода с C, C++ на код PHP?

Comment: А как Вы себе это представляете? :)

Comment: Возможно, автор вдохновился существованием программ, делающих обратное преобразование (я имею в виду штуку, которую разрабатывают для Мордокниги). Как правильно подметил cy6erGn0m, никакого резона не просматривается…

Answer (score 4):

Ну.. вообще-то, теоретически есть ряд серьзёных сложностей, которые непонятно как с ходу решить. И даже если бы кто-то что-то придумал, то это потребовало бы серьёзных затрат ресурсов. Это было бы что-то дорогое иными словами.

И, наконец, последнее: зачем вам такая тула? Почему вы не можете C-код просто скомпилировать, а потом обратиться к нему из PHP? Это будет намного эффективнее со всех точек зрения. Чтобы осуществить затею, можете воспользоваться автоматическими тулами, напрмиер, [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/).

Учитывая эти два момента, маловероятно, что такая тула существует.

Comment: Кстати, как-то тоже возникал такой вопрос, но на третьи сутки я, разобравшись более-менее с особенностями, понял, что как бы трудно ни было переписать код С->PHP, лучше сделать это руками. И то смысл может быть, если там чистый матан. Сишное [(char) (&a + (ubsigned int) --b * (signed char) getch())] транслировать в php - смерти подобно, не считай перегруженных операторов.

Comment: Ну, перегруженные операторы очень легко перевести. Вас ведь никто не заствялет делать сгенерированный код иедально похожим на исходный. Важно ведь чтобы он работал так же. А вот операции с указателями могут быть дейтсвительно сложны.

Answer (score 1):

Такой перевод невозможен и вряд ли будет когда-либо возможен

Если целью является использование С-кода в PHP - в 7.4 завезут [FFI](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/intro.ffi.php)